# Is it possible to select items from an array where a certain property is met using Select-Object?

Tags: powershell

For example, `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, Length` returns the name with the length, but is it possible to select only items with a specific name (excluding the paramater of Get-ChildItem itself.)?

Comment: Would you accept using **Where-Object**?  For example `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object Name -eq 'Something' | Select-Object Name, Length`

Comment: Yes. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the name (or other property value) using [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6).

For your example, using the **where** alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet name and omitting all optional parameter names :

```
Get-ChildItem | Where Name -eq 'Something' | Select Name, Length
```

Note as mentioned in the the link unless specified the [comparison operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) is case insensitive.  If you wanted to select a file called `Something` but not `SomeTHING` you would prepend a `c`.  For example :

```
Get-ChildItem | Where Name -ceq 'Something' | Select Name, Length
```

This syntax applies to PowerShell 3.0 and later.